# Как получить значение lineEdit при вызове функции из модуля?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer

я начинаю изучать Python и PyQt и у меня появился вопрос насчёт вызова функции из модуля и работы с объектами PyQt.

Есть **`3`** файла. Мне нужно получить значение из `lineEdit` в функции **Second.py**, а затем вызвать эту функцию в **First.py**.

Но значение в `lineEdit` задаётся внутри **First.py**. `lineEdit` изначально создан в файле **design.py**

Ниже приведён упрощённый код:

**design.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'design.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 190, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 190, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

**First.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import design
from Second import Hax


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.lineEdit.setText("Текст для ввода")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Test)

    def Test(self):
        Hax().calc()


def main():
    App = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = App()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = App()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Second.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import design


class Hax(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def calc(self):
        print(self.lineEdit.text())
        print("Текст?")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотя я не совсем понимаю что будет дальше, но попробуйте передать `self.lineEdit.text()` при вызове метода `calc(self.lineEdit.text())`

**q1300772_design.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 190, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 190, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

**q1300772_First.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import q1300772_design
from q1300772_Second import Hax


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, q1300772_design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("q1300772_First")
        
        self.lineEdit.setText("Текст для ввода")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Test)
        
        self.second = Hax()                                          # +++

    def Test(self):
#        Hax().calc()
        self.second.calc(self.lineEdit.text())                       # +++ self.lineEdit.text()
        

''' ???
def main():
    App = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = App()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = App()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1300772_Second.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import q1300772_design


class Hax(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, q1300772_design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("q1300772_Second...")

    def calc(self, text):                                        # +++ text
#        print(self.lineEdit.text())

        print("Текст ?", text)                                   # +++ text
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> но это несколько другое решение, которое я хотел найти. Возможно, я неправильно выразился в начальной постановке. В полной версии кода, из self.lineEdit я получаю текст и использую внутри функции calc. Ваше решение было бы идеальным если бы число используемых объектов было небольшим, а так мне нужно будет передать более 10 lineEdit.

Вот вам другой вариант:

**q1300772_First.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import q1300772_design
from q1300772_Second import Hax


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, q1300772_design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("q1300772_First")
        
        self.lineEdit.setText("Текст для ввода")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Test)
        
        self.second = Hax(self)                                 # +++ self

    def Test(self):
        self.second.calc()                                      # +++       


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = App()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1300772_Second.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import q1300772_design


class Hax(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, q1300772_design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                              # +++ parent=None
        super().__init__(parent)                                  # +++ parent
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("q1300772_Second...")
        
        self.parent = parent                                      # +++ 

    def calc(self):                                        
        print("Текст ?", self.parent.lineEdit.text())             # +++ self.parent...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это несколько другое решение, которое я хотел найти. Возможно, я неправильно выразился в начальной постановке. В полной версии кода, из self.lineEdit я получаю текст и использую внутри функции calc. Ваше решение было бы идеальным если бы число используемых объектов было небольшим, а так мне нужно будет передать более 10 lineEdit.

Comment: @Wexel я добавил второе возможное решение - проверьте. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Большое спасибо!)